# Cannot map EF Core discriminator column to enum on existing column

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-8.0

I am attempting to get EF Core 8.0.2's type-per-hiearchy configuration working with an enum used for the discriminator. If you consider the following C# 12 code:

```cs
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Builders;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

using var context = new TestDbContext();
await context.Database.EnsureDeletedAsync();
await context.Database.EnsureCreatedAsync();

await context.SaveChangesAsync();

var items = await context.Items.ToListAsync();
foreach (var item in items)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.ToString());
}

public enum BaseItemType
{
    ConcreteA = 0,
    ConcreteB = 1
}

public abstract class BaseItem
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public BaseItemType Type { get; set; }
}

public class ConcreteItemA : BaseItem
{
    public ConcreteItemA()
    {
        Type = BaseItemType.ConcreteA;
    }
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public override string ToString() => $"{Id,3}|{Name,10}|{Number,10:G2}";
}

public class ConcreteItemB : BaseItem
{
    public ConcreteItemB()
    {
        Type = BaseItemType.ConcreteB;
    }
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }
    public override string ToString() => $"{Id,3}|{Name,10}|{Amount,10:C2}";
}

public class TestDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<BaseItem> Items => Set<BaseItem>();

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder
            .UseSqlite("Data Source=items.db;Cache=Shared")
            .LogTo(Console.WriteLine, LogLevel.Debug)
            .EnableDetailedErrors();
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly(GetType().Assembly);
    }
}

public abstract class BaseItemTypeConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<BaseItem>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<BaseItem> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable("Items")
            .HasDiscriminator<BaseItemType>("Type")
            .HasValue<ConcreteItemB>(BaseItemType.ConcreteB)
            .HasValue<ConcreteItemA>(BaseItemType.ConcreteA)
            .IsComplete();

        builder.HasKey(b => b.Id);
        builder.Property(b => b.Id).IsRequired().ValueGeneratedOnAdd();

        Configure(builder);
    }
}

public class ConcreteItemATypeConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<ConcreteItemA>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<ConcreteItemA> builder)
    {
        builder.Property(b => b.Number).HasDefaultValue(42);
        builder.HasData(new ConcreteItemA { Id = 1, Name = "A", Number = 41 });
    }
}

public class ConcreteItemBTypeConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<ConcreteItemB>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<ConcreteItemB> builder)
    {
        builder.Property(b => b.Amount).HasDefaultValue(42.0M);
        builder.HasData(new ConcreteItemB { Id = 2, Name = "B", Amount = 41.0M });
    }
}
```

The code generates the expected output; however, the database schema that is created does not match my expectations. Instead of using the `Type` column, it adds a shadow property named `Discriminator` of type `text`, and populates it with the string values of the enum, in addition to populating the `type` field with the integer values of the enum. I can see the following message in the logs:

> The property 'BaseItem.Discriminator' was created in shadow state because there are no eligible CLR members with a matching name.

So EF Core generates the following SQL to create and populate the table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE "Items" (
  "Id" INTEGER NOT NULL CONSTRAINT "PK_Items" PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
  "Name" TEXT NOT NULL,
  "Type" INTEGER NOT NULL,
  "Discriminator" TEXT NOT NULL,
  "Number" INTEGER NULL DEFAULT 42,
  "Amount" TEXT NULL DEFAULT '42.0'
);
INSERT INTO "Items" ("Id", "Discriminator", "Name", "Number", "Type")
VALUES (1, 'ConcreteItemA', 'A', 41, 0);
SELECT changes();
INSERT INTO "Items" ("Id", "Amount", "Discriminator", "Name", "Type")
VALUES (2, '41.0', 'ConcreteItemB', 'B', 1);
SELECT changes();
```

and the following query to retrieve the values:

```sql
SELECT "i"."Id", "i"."Discriminator", "i"."Name", "i"."Type", "i"."Number", "i"."Amount"
FROM "Items" AS "i"
```

How do I stop EF Core from adding the shadow `Discriminator` property to the table? I tried using the following in `BaseItemTypeConfiguration` without success:

```cs
builder.ToTable("Items")
    .HasDiscriminator(b => b.Type)
    .HasValue<ConcreteItemB>(BaseItemType.ConcreteB)
    .HasValue<ConcreteItemA>(BaseItemType.ConcreteA)
    .IsComplete();
```

Comment: Try `.HasDiscriminator<int>(b => b.Type)`  might need to cast the `HasValue` with `(int)` BaseItemType.ConcreteX)` Though it looks like it should have worked. EF Core does support resolving enums as integers or strings, from memory at least with PK/FK it seems to default to integer. Seems like odd behavior.

Comment: 'public **abstract** class BaseItemTypeConfiguration', if that's true, then your base configuration code is simply not called.